# connect apollo server with mongodb mongoos

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, graphql, apollo-server

I'm trying to connect apollo-server with my mongodb on mlab (I tried with my local mongo as well). I can connect to the db fine, although nothing is returned when testing with a graphql query. I just can't figure out how to actually get the data back from the db. I am using the latest apollo-server-express.

I've put this together from various tutorials and the docs but can't find a clear answer on my problem. Probably missing something very obvious.

**Server.js**

```
import express from 'express';
import { ApolloServer, gql } from 'apollo-server-express';
import Mongoose from 'mongoose';

import { Post } from './models/Post';

const app = express();

Mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

Mongoose.connect('mongodb://<username>:<pw>@ds151282.mlab.com:51282/groupin', { useNewUrlParser: true })
  .then(()=> console.log('DB connected'))
  .catch(error => console.log(error))

const typeDefs = gql`
  type Post {
    title: String
    description: String
    author: String
    url: String
  }
  type Query {
    allPosts: [Post]
  }
`;

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    allPosts(parent, args) {
      return Post.find({})
    }
  }
};


const apollo = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs, 
  resolvers,
  context: ({req}) => ({ Post })
});

apollo.applyMiddleware({ app })

app.listen(4000, () => {
  console.log(` Server ready at http://localhost:4000${apollo.graphqlPath}`);
});
```

**Post.js**

```
import Mongoose from 'mongoose';

const PostSchema = {
  title: String,
  description: String,
  author: String,
  url: String
};

const Post = Mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);
export { Post };
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to use mongoose Schema instead of plain object

**Post.js**

```
import Mongoose from 'mongoose';

const PostSchema = new Mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  description: String,
  author: String,
  url: String
});

const Post = Mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);
export { Post };
```